# Codeigniter video upload is not working in live server

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, codeigniter-3, video-upload

I am using following code to upload video in my codeigniter project.

**This is my view code**

```
<?php echo $error;?>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>
    <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
    <input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

**This is controller**

```
class Upload extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }
    public function do_upload()
    {
        $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|mp4';
        $config['max_size']             = 100000;
        $config['max_width']            = 1024;
        $config['max_height']           = 768;
    
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            var_dump($error);
        }
        else
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    }
}
```

This code working fine through xampp. But I'm facing error in live server/cpanl. When I try to upload video every time it shows following error,

```
array(1) { 
    ["error"]=> string(43) 
    "You did not select a file to upload." }
```

Comment: Did you click on the userfile tag before you hit submit?

Comment: of course I did.

Comment: Have you selected a file?

Comment: yes I have selected.

Comment: What server do you use? Is it Apache? Or Nginx?

Comment: might be related to size, try with a very small <100k video to see if it works, if it does, you need to change your file-size settings in CI, php.ini and eventually server

Answer (score 0):

> Looks like uploads or functions might be disabled inside php.ini
> trying running your code with error_reporting(E_ALL); to see if some
> error occured except for You did not select a file to upload. error

Comment: ok.. but my code is working fine for .jpg, .png, .gif or else. facing error only for video file in cpanel/live server. but video file is also working fine through xampp.